# Zope form : adding a button to automatically fill some fields

Tags: forms, zope

under Plone4/Zope3, I have a form to add a new object.

I'd like to add a button after the first field, to do the following : 
- the user enters the value for the first field
- he presses this new button 
- and the server will try to guess the remaining field based on the first field and an external database. 
- the user will then have to check if all fields are OK and then submit the form.

I am not a zope expert, and spent some time trying to figure out how to do this.

Is creating a subform a good idea ?

If not, I could add a new button to the form : I tried something like 
    @button.buttonAndHandler(_(u'Essai'))
    def essai(self, action):
        print "button essai"

but then I have the following issues :
- how to render the button after the first field and not at the bottom ?
- how to update the remaining fields without submitting the form ?
- how to keep the "add" and "cancel" button that disappeared when I added this essai button.

any hints ?
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use javascript to solve this. With jquery you can include an extra button directly behind your first field (http://api.jquery.com/after). In the button action ask a browser view for the search results in json (http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) an fill up the other form fields, like:

```
jq('my-button').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var first_field= jq('#first-field-id').val();
    jq.getJSON('/@@my-browser-view?value=' + value, function(result) {
        jq('#other-field-id').val(result.val_for_other_field);
        ...
    });
});
```